# NoClassDefFoundError and already use multidex Android OS Below Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, runtime-error

I am getting this error in my `Application`, I have already use `multidex` on my `Application` but still getting this error but If i am tested on My Android Os Above Lolipop it runs smoothly without this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.woserba.tokoadmin, PID: 2853
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.woserba.tokoadmin.penjualan.ProductPenjualanCartActivity
                      at com.woserba.tokoadmin.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:44)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please suggest me.

This is My Code for the activity

```
public class ProductPenjualanCartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener,NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private ArrayList<CartPenjualan> listSuperHeroes,listcart;
private ProductPenjualanAdapter prd;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

private RequestQueue requestQueue;

private Button btnbarcode,btnreset;
private int requestCount = 1;
private static String stringip;
private String terima;
private SharedPreferences sharepreferens;

private int hot_number = 0;
private TextView ui_hot = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_penjualancart);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    btnbarcode=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBarcode);
    btnreset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    //Initializing Views
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    btnbarcode.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnreset.setOnClickListener(this);
    //Initializing our superheroes list
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    listcart=new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == fab) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    //Calling method to get data to fetch data
    getData();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {
                    getData();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
    }

    prd = new ProductPenjualanAdapter(listSuperHeroes, this);
    prd.setButtonListener(new ProductPenjualanAdapter.ButtonListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(View view, int yourInfo,int v) {

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(yourInfo), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(listcart.size()>0)
            {
                String infoganti=null;
                for(int i=0;i < listcart.size();i++)
                {
                    if(listcart.get(i).getIdbarang().contains(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getIdbarang()))
                    {
                        listcart.get(i).setQtybarang(v);
                        infoganti=String.valueOf(i);
                    }
                }
                if(infoganti==null) {
                    CartPenjualan cartproduct = new CartPenjualan();
                    cartproduct.setIdbarang(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getIdbarang());
                    cartproduct.setImageUrl(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getImageUrl());
                    cartproduct.setName(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getName());
                    cartproduct.setMerek(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getMerek());
                    cartproduct.setHarga(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getHarga());
                    cartproduct.setQtybarang(v);
                    listcart.add(cartproduct);
                }
                updateHotCount(listcart.size());
            } else if(listcart.size()==0){
                CartPenjualan cartproduct = new CartPenjualan();
                cartproduct.setIdbarang(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getIdbarang());
                cartproduct.setImageUrl(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getImageUrl());
                cartproduct.setName(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getName());
                cartproduct.setMerek(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getMerek());
                cartproduct.setHarga(listSuperHeroes.get(yourInfo).getHarga());
                cartproduct.setQtybarang(v);
                listcart.add(cartproduct);
                updateHotCount(listcart.size());
            }
        }

    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(prd);
}
```

Comment: what are you using? FireBase?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: @Raju i am already look that question but still not solved for my error

Comment: @RushiAyyappa i am using volley not use firebase

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: @RushiAyyappa I am already Update my Post,Thank You for your help